# How to add Custom placeholder icon in intelinput javascript plugin

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, sass

**Html**

```
<input type="tel" id="phone">
```

**javascript**

```
     var input = document.querySelector("#phone");
     window.intlTelInput(input, {
     separateDialCode:true,
    utilsScript: "../scripts/utils.js",
    customPlaceholder: function(selectedCountryPlaceholder, selectedCountryData) {
      return "e.g. " + selectedCountryPlaceholder;
    },
  });
```

**I want to show custom circle icon default, when I click on the dropdown then it shows different country but first custom icon placeholder**

Answer (score 0):

Just add the placeholder attribute in the input as follow

```
<input type="tel" id="phone" placeholder="THIS IS PLACEHOLDER">
```